# What is a member sub object?

Tags: c++, object, language-lawyer

A search in the C++ ISO draft 2020, Document Number 4849, for the term "member subobject" return 7 results. All of them are transcribed below;

(6.7.2 Object Model):

> Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can
> be a **member subobject** (11.4), a base class subobject (11.7), or an
> array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object
> is called a complete object. If an object is created in storage
> associated with a **member subobject** or array element e (which may or
> may not be within its lifetime), the created object is a subobject of
> e’s containing object if:...

(6.7.3 Lifetime)

> [Note: 11.10.2 describes the lifetime of base and **member subobjects**. —
> end note]

(9.9 The using declaration)

> [Note: Because a using-declarator designates a base class member (and
> not a **member subobject** or a member function of a base class
> subobject), a using-declarator cannot be used to resolve inherited
> member ambiguities

(11.4 Class Member)

> [Note: A non-static data member of non-reference type is a **member
> subobject** of a class object (6.7.2). — end note]

(11.8 Member Name Lookup)

> [Note: A static member, a nested type or an enumerator defined in a
> base class T can unambiguously be found even if an object has more
> than one base class subobject of type T. Two base class subobjects
> share the non-static **member subobjects** of their common virtual base
> classes. — end note]

(11.10.2 initializing bases and members)

> Note: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and **member
> subobjects** are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization. — end
> note]

No one of them seems to be a definition of the term for me. The Class Member statement above says something interesting, but it doensn't say that "**Only** non-static data members of non referecente types are member subobjects". So What is member subobject?

Comment: _The Class Member statement above says something interesting_ But not really correct. NSDM is not a subobject, the same way as variable is not an object. Even thought there is an association between them in some circumstances.

Comment: Should I give up on this term? It looks too messy

Comment: I think the distinction @LanguageLawyer is making is that if you have a NSDM `int x` that is a "member" but not a "member subobject"

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes, NSDM is basically what can be declared or found by name lookup. `int x` in `struct S { int x; };` declares NSDM, `S::x` denotes (in the sense of lookup, not in the sense of [\[basic.lval\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lval#def:glvalue)) NSDM etc. But there are no member subobjects here. Member subobject is a «thing» which can correspond to a NSDM in, say, class member access expression. `S{}.x` denotes (or designates, in [basic.lva]/1 sense) a member subobject of the temporary object created from `S{}` corresponding to `S::x` NSDM.

Comment: Can you show some C++ code where it is not clear whether something is a member subobject or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
struct A {
};

struct B {
    A a;
}

int main()
{
    A x;
    B y;
}
```

In this case `x` is a "complete object" of type `A`, whereas while `y.a` is also of type `A` it is a "member subobject" of the object `y` which is type `B`.

Comment: I was thinking something like this . But what would happen if the struct B were derived from A? It would exist a unnamed object of type A inside B that would be a base class subobject. So the `A a` would be a member subobject and the unnamed `A`  not?