# How the process of member look up occurs in C++?

Tags: c++, name-lookup

I'm using the document number 4901, C++ Draft ISO 2021, specifically 6.5.2 (Member Name Lookup). I'm failing in understanding a lot of uses of the terms "member subobject" and "base class subobjects". I already asked about these terms in : [What is a member sub object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742594/what-is-a-member-sub-object?noredirect=1#comment123278087_69742594) and
[What is a base class subobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738775/what-is-a-base-class-subobject/69739162?noredirect=1#comment123290355_69739162)

The Second question had an answer relatively satisfactory for me, the first one although didn't help me. I'm thinking that the explanation in the draft is a little too abstract, so I would rely on a rigorous defitnion of the terms cited above, but really didn't find any. Taking another path, How the member name look up occurs in practice? How the terms:  *member subobject* and *base class subobject* are related to member names lookup?

Comment: The exact mechanism is a compiler-internal implementation detail. The standard only specifies what the result should be, and it's not clear what you believe is missing from the standard text in that regard.

Comment: In the merge process cited in 6.5.2 there are a lot of use of these two types of subobjects, which are not well defined in the draft (in my opinion)

Comment: A "member subobject" is a subobject that is a member. A "base class subobject" is a subobject that is an instance of a base class. (This is normal English.) I don't see how anyone needs more definition than that.

Comment: How can I know what is normal english, what is language specification? In 6.7.2 it's said that a object can be these two and a array. These two terms are in itallic. In 6.2 Declarations are said to (re)introduce names and entities, but no change in the style of the word occurs and is not just a english word here(I think)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an ABI standpoint, there is very little distinction between `B` and `C` in the following:

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

struct B : A {};

struct C {
  A base;
};
```

Creating an object of type `B` or `C` both require creating an object of type `A`. In both cases, the instance of `A` *belongs* to the parent object. So in both cases they are *sub-objects*.

For objects of type `B`, the `A` object is a *base class sub-object*.

For objects of type `C`, the `A` object is a *member sub-object*.

**Edit**: integrating stuff from followup questions in the comments.

```
struct D : A {
  A base;
};
```

In `D`'s case, there are 2 sub-objects of type `A` in each instance of `D`. One *base class sub-object* **and** one *member sub-object*.

Comment: Clarified much more! In the last two sentences `For B, the A object is a *base class subobject*`. It is for the B class itself or for the instance of B?

Comment: @Roman it's a subobject of instances.

Comment: Frank, what if there was a `A child` inside B? Something Like:
`struct B : A {A child;};`. Would this be a base class subobject or member subobject?

Comment: @Roman There would be 2 subobjects, one base class subobject AND one member subobject.

Comment: But child is a subobject and a instance of a base class right? What I understood from the molbdnilo comment is that it should be a base class subobject.So Just the implicit object created are base class subobject ?

Comment: @Roman no, The A subobject and the A base class are two separate objects. Think of it like a struct having 2 members with different names and the same type. `struct Vec2 {int x; int y;}`

Comment: Good explanation. To add a bit more from programmer's (as opposed to  ABI) perspective: *base class sub-object* is *inherited* and unnamed whereas *member sub-object* is *embedded* and can be accessed by its name. Inheritance is related to the "A-**is**-B" relation, whereas embedding with the "A-**has**-B" relation. All this relates to HOW the subobject can be used in a program in a valid way.